# SQL Find Max of one Column based on Duplicate in another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an interesting SQL problem that I'm not sure the best way to solve. I need to select the max/highest ID number (CatalogVersionID) based IF the CatalogID's are equal:

```
+------------------+-----------+----------------------+
| CatalogVersionID | CatalogID | CatalogVersionNumber |
+------------------+-----------+----------------------+
|              121 |       492 |                0.0.2 |
|              122 |       493 |                0.0.2 |
|              123 |       494 |                0.0.1 |
|              201 |       572 |                1.0.0 |
|              207 |       494 |                0.1.0 |
+------------------+-----------+----------------------+
```

So, the above should only output one row for `CatalogID = 494`, and it should be the row with `CatalogVersionID = 207` and `CatalogVersionNumber = 0.1.0`, while also returning the 3 other rows without duplicate `CatalogID`'s I am trying to get the most recent version for a catalog.

I have tried some failed solutions using max, and some self-joining queries with no luck. The eventual solution will need to be fed a `GroupID` (separate table) and return the desired results. I will do some joining of tables to get that part, and think I can handle that much, I'm just having trouble returning the correct/max `CatalogVersionID` from results like the above:

**Desired output:**

```
+------------------+-----------+----------------------+
| CatalogVersionID | CatalogID | CatalogVersionNumber |
+------------------+-----------+----------------------+
|              121 |       492 |                0.0.2 |
|              122 |       493 |                0.0.2 |
|              201 |       572 |                1.0.0 |
|              207 |       494 |                0.1.0 |
+------------------+-----------+----------------------+
```

Here is something I've tried that only gets the max `CatalogVersionID` for the entire result set (this shows the other tables being joined):

```
select cv.*
From CatalogBuilder.CatalogVersion cv
JOIN(select max(c.CatalogVersionID) as max_id
        from [CatalogBuilder].[CatalogVersion] c
        inner join [CatalogBuilder].[Catalog] cat on c.CatalogID = cat.CatalogID
        inner join [CatalogBuilder].[Group] g on g.GroupID = cat.GroupID
        where g.GroupID = 157) 
b on b.max_id = cv.CatalogVersionID
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following using a `GROUP BY` on `CatalogID` in a sub-select to get the highest `CatalogVersionID`. With an additional `INNER JOIN` you can select all the needed rows:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM table_name t1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT CatalogID, MAX(CatalogVersionID) AS CatalogVersionID 
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY CatalogID
) t2 ON t1.CatalogID = t2.CatalogID 
    AND t1.CatalogVersionID = t2.CatalogVersionID
```

> **demo:** https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3d92a5630c71aebb79d3562c9bf8c2dd

Comment: Nope, this actually works perfectly for my needs. Sorry if that wasn't clear @digital.aaron. You're a life saver Sebastian Brosch!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the test data in table form:

```
CREATE TABLE #test (CatalogVersionID INT,  CatalogID INT, CatalogVersionNumber VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #test
(
    CatalogVersionID
    ,CatalogID
    ,CatalogVersionNumber
)
VALUES
(121,492,'0.0.2'),
(122,493,'0.0.2'),
(123,494,'0.0.1'),
(201,572,'1.0.0'),
(207,494,'0.1.0')
```

We can use a CTE to number the rows in each CatalogId grouping, ordering by the CatalogVersionID descending. Then we ouput only those rows where row number = 1.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        t.CatalogVersionID
        , t.CatalogID
        , t.CatalogVersionNumber 
        , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.CatalogID ORDER BY t.CatalogVersionID DESC)
    FROM #test t
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Output is:

```
CatalogVersionID    CatalogID   CatalogVersionNumber    rn
121                 492         0.0.2                   1
122                 493         0.0.2                   1
207                 494         0.1.0                   1
201                 572         1.0.0                   1
```

Comment: This looks like it would've worked as well. Greatly appreciate your input and help Aaron!